# Scala Actor Prime Sieve

Tags: scala, actor, primes

I'm a newish java coder who was recently told to check out scala for its concurrent implementation.  I figured a simple (albeit not the best for illustrating concurrency) example might be to have actors solve the Sieve of Eratosthenes.  I've cobbled something together thusfar, but I'm not really sure if the direction I'm going is even close to correct.  Here's my current code:

```
import scala.actors.Actor
import scala.actors.Actor._
import Array._

class PrimeActor(val id: Int) extends Actor {

     //Runs one Prime of the Sieve of Eratosthenes
     def sieve(p: Int, list: Array[Int]) {
       var i = 1
       var place = 0
       while(list contains (i * p)) {
       place = list.indexOf(i * p)
       if (list(place) != 0) 
          list.update(place, 0)
       i += 1
       }
     }

   //Checks to see if there is a higher prime in the list
   //If so, creates a new actor to handle it and sends
   //it the list and the prime
   def findandCreateNextPrime(p: Int, list: Array[Int]){
      var i = 1
      var place = list.indexOf(p)
      while(list(place + i) == 0 && (p + i) <= list.last) {
         i += 1
      }
      val newP = list(place+i)

      if (list contains (p + i)) {
         if ((p + i) equals list.last) {
            print(list.last)
         } else {
            print(", ")
            val pA = new PrimeActor(newP)
            pA.start()
            pA ! (list(newP), list)
         } 
     } else {
     println("DONE")
    } 
  }

   //Actor behavior
   def act() {
      loop {
         react{
            case (recievedP: Int, recievedList: Array[Int]) =>
               print(recievedP)
               sieve(recievedP, recievedList)
               findandCreateNextPrime(recievedP, recievedList)
               exit()
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Any help or directional input would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Scala you can write your code in a functional style. I suggest you to use it. Firstly forget about the `Array`, it is a mutable collection and mutable collections in scala are evil. Better use immutable collections as `List`. The same is to say about `var`. Try to use `val` where possible.

The simplest way to implement the sieve of Eratosthenes in Scala, I can guess, is the following:

```
import scala.annotations.tailrec

def sieve(until: Int): Seq[Int] = {
  @tailrec
  def loop(i: Int, primes: Seq[Int]): Seq[Int] = {
    // we reached the desired end
    if (i > until) primes
    else {
      // we already found a factor of this i
      if (primes exists(i % _ == 0)) loop(i + 2, primes)
      // we found a new prime
      else loop(i + 2, primes :+ i)
    }
  }
  // there is no prime smaller than 2
  if (until < 2) Seq.empty[Int]
  // starting with 3 has the advantage, we only need to check i + 2
  else loop(3, Seq.empty[Int] :+ 2)
}
```

If you just started using Scala this might be a litle confusing, but I will explain.

We want a sequence of all primes until a specific number. We define a recursive function, which will check every second number if it is a prime or not. Because it is tailrecursive, the complier will optimate it to a for-comprehension, so we don't need to bother about `StackOverflow`s. If our counter passes the maximum (`until`), we return the primes, we detected. This is our recursion-anchor. Otherwise we check wether we found a prime, which is a factor of our curent `i`. If there is one, we just skip to the next candidate, else we add `i` to our primes and go on the the next candidate.

Note: The annotation is not necesarry, but if it exists, the compiler while warn you, if the function is not tailrecursive.

Using my suggested code leads us to the problem, you can't use concurency anymore. A good introduction for concurency in scala, is a chapter from [Programming Scala](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/). They solved the sleeping barber problem via concurency. Here is a [link](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9780596155957/Concurrency.html) to their solution.

Answer (score -1):

Actors are about concurrency: different tasks being done concurrently, communicating with each other as necessary.

There are two very important things about actors:

1. You only talk to actors through messages. If your actor is not sending a message back with the return, or is getting information from somewhere other than a message, you are doing it wrong.
2. You do not send mutable data structures to actors. If you do it, you are doing it wrong.

So, you break both rules in your example, and there's really no interaction between actors. For these reason, actors are probably the wrong choice here. In such cases, it's perhaps better to look at the parallel collections for answers, but they won't help you here either.

The Sieve of Eratosthenes is an inherently serial algorithm, and a bad choice for either parallelism or concurrency.

Comment: as soon as a prime `p` is found, why not fire up a separate worker to go along an array and mark each `p`-th number as non-prime, as the sieve must do? Is there a difficulty in communicating back a progress of each worker so that master doesn't get ahead of any of them? Is the gain too small? I'm speaking from a position of complete ignorance here. But I expected the sieve to be actually a good candidate for concurrency: **P** = {3,5, ...} \ **U** {{p^2, p^2+2p, ...} | p in **P**} , plus `2`.

Comment: @WillNess There's a synchronization issue in not allowing the master to get ahead of what the other actors are doing, but, more importantly, how do you use the results from the other actors? If you inquire each one of them, that's way too expensive. If you need to combine the results, that's more expensive than computing them in first place.

Comment: Can't they work on *one* mutually accessible mutable array? Can just that one exception be made here? In effect this array being sieved *is* their communication device (recording the results of progress of each one along the array)... They don't *read* from it, only *write* to it, does it help in allowing this perhaps? The master would expect for just two messages from each worker: 1. completed the first step 2. done.

Comment: @WillNess No, they cannot. Actors must not share mutable state. If they do, they are not actors. Note that I'm not a frothing-at-the-mouth hardcore purist here; however, if you do share mutable state, you are not doing actors, you are just doing multithreading with a heavy layer of indirection between your code and the threads. *Beyond that*, having multiple threads update the same array will kill your CPU cache so much so the single threaded solution is bound to be faster.